# Solve $\frac{|x|}{|x-1|}+|x|=\frac{x^2}{|x-1|}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

Solve $\frac{|x|}{|x-1|}+|x|=\frac{x^2}{|x-1|}$.What will be the easiest techique to solve this sum ?
*Just wanted to share a special type of equation and the fastest way to solve it.I am not asking for an answer and i have solved it in my answer given below.Thank You for viewing.*

Comment: Break it up into cases or regions--there are three: 1) $x > 1$, 2) $0 < x < 1$, and 3) $x < 0$.  You should solve each equation and then discard any found solutions that are outside of the region you are looking at.

Answer (score 6):

To me the easiest and most systematic way to solve it is to explicitly write out the absolute value which means breaking the equation into regions:

$$
\frac{|x|}{|x - 1|} + |x| = \frac{x^2}{|x - 1|} \rightarrow \begin{cases}
\left(\frac{1}{x - 1} + 1\right)x = \frac{x^2}{x - 1} & 1 < x < \infty \\ 
\left(\frac{1}{1 - x} + 1\right)x = \frac{x^2}{1 - x} & 0 \leq x < 1 \\
-\left(\frac{1}{1 - x} + 1\right)x = \frac{x^2}{1 - x} & -\infty < x < 0
\end{cases}
$$

$\frac{1}{x - 1} + 1 = \frac{1 + x - 1}{x - 1} = \frac{x}{x - 1}$ and $\frac{1}{1 - x} + 1 = \frac{1 + 1 - x}{1 - x} = \frac{2 - x}{1 - x}$ which gives:

$$
\frac{|x|}{|x - 1|} + |x| = \frac{x^2}{|x - 1|} \rightarrow \begin{cases}
\frac{x^2 - x^2}{x - 1} = 0 & 1 < x < \infty \\ 
\frac{2x - x^2 - x^2}{1 - x} = 0 & 0 \leq x < 1 \\
\frac{-2x + x^2 - x^2}{1 - x} = 0 & -\infty < x < 0
\end{cases}
$$

Which gives:

$$
\frac{|x|}{|x - 1|} + |x| = \frac{x^2}{|x - 1|} \rightarrow \begin{cases}
0 = 0 & 1 < x < \infty \\ 
2x\frac{1 - x}{1 - x} = 0 & 0 \leq x < 1 \\
-\frac{2x}{1 - x} = 0 & -\infty < x < 0
\end{cases}
$$

Which means that this equation is true for *all* (real) values $x > 1$ and $x = 0$--there are no negative values of $x$ which satisfy this equation since the third case only has a solution at $x = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

*A shortcut formula for such sums is if $|f(x)|+|g(x)|=|f(x)+g(x)|$ then $f(x).g(x)>0$ then $[\frac{x}{x-1}][x]>=0$ which implies $x^2(x-1)>=0$.But $x^2$ is always >=0.Hence **$x>1$** is the solution as well as x=0.*

Comment: Corrected :-)!!

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, $x-1\ne0\iff x\ne1$

and $x^2=|x|(1+|x-1|)\ge0\implies x$ is real

So, $x^2=|x^2|\implies |x|(1+|x-1|-|x|)=0$

If $|x|=0, x=0$

Else $1+|x-1|-|x|=0$

We know  for real $y,|y|=+y$ if $y\ge0$ and $-y$ if $y<0$

So, test for $x<0,0\le x<1,x\ge1$